# How to redirect to specific route in ionic4 on click of push notification?

Tags: ionic4, ionic-native, cordova-plugin-fcm

How to redirect to specific route in ionic4 on click of push notification? 
P.S. I am using: [this](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/fcm)

Answer (score 2):

According to the [documentation](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/fcm) of your plugin that you're using you can use the following code:

```
this.fcm.onNotification().subscribe(data => {
  if(data.wasTapped){
    console.log("Received in background");
  } else {
    console.log("Received in foreground");
  };
});
```

You can then implement the Angular router to route from to a specific route:

```
this.router.navigate([path]);
```

Comment: when the app is killed, and I try to open the app it does not go to a specific page. it goes on home page.